# Formality and politeness of the word fine

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I was wondering what I should use to sound more polite.

"If you are with it" or
"If it is fine with you?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using an auxiliary verb in your sentence may make it sound more polite.

You could try the following: "Will this be all right with you?"